# How to use data in excel sheet using PowerShell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I want to do some tricky things to use excel data in PowerShell. I have the following table in the excel sheet.

[image]

I want to use PowerShell to read the data from this table and do a simple calculation. For example, `if ($Reader = Seafreight) {$Result = $TransportE * $CO2footprint}` But I do not know how to import the excel data into PowerShell as variables.
Any ideas?

Comment: There are solutions for this depending on your needs. Here is a [custom cmdlet](https://podlisk.wordpress.com/2011/11/20/import-excel-spreadsheet-into-powershell/) for importing for example. You could also just export to CSV from excel and import using `Import-csv` which is simpler. Depends on what your end game is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

First put the following function into you Powershell profile, this will give you a Get-Clipboard cmdlet which will always be available.

```
function Get-Clipboard([switch] $Lines) {
    if($Lines) {
        $cmd = {
            Add-Type -Assembly PresentationCore
            [Windows.Clipboard]::GetText() -replace "`r", '' -split "`n"
        }
    } else {
        $cmd = {
            Add-Type -Assembly PresentationCore
            [Windows.Clipboard]::GetText()
        }
    }
    if([threading.thread]::CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() -eq 'MTA') {
        & powershell -Sta -Command $cmd
    } else {
        & $cmd
    }
}
```

Then all you need to is copy your table from Excel (make sure you have a header for each column) then type the following into your Powershell console:

```
$data = Get-Clipboard | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t"
$data
```